# How to change currentlocale programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I would like to change the current locale programmatically. I tried searching in stackoverflow and found this way.

```
[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

But my question is how to set it to the currentLocale, but [NSLocale currentLocale] returns the currentLocale. But how do I set it?

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: no changing the language... changing the region format...

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I am not looking for changing the language on the fly. Looking for changing the region format...

Comment: You should not (and cannot) change the current locale, but rather to create a new `NSLocale` object like you have above, and then use this locale object for whatever purposes you need (e.g. calling the `setLocale` of a `NSDateFormatter`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change language programmtically so that Locale will change accordingly.

> UserDefaults.standard.set(["en_us"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")

although i didn't get time to try this solution(In swift)